# $unwind with group and count

Tags: python, mongodb

All my fields are an array - many of them comprise just one element, but I cannot get the unwind behaving correctly, and I don't see why.

```
field = ['A']
```

or `field = ['A', 'B']`

```
pipeline = [ {"$unwind": "$field"}, 
            {"$group": {"_id": "$field", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }, 
            {"$sort": {"_id" : 1} }, 
            ]
```

However in my results, I'm seeing a record as `[{"_id": ['A', 'B'], "count": 5}]` where I would like `[{"_id": ['A'], "count": 5}, {"_id": ['B'], "count": 5}]`

It seems the unwind is not working as it should, but I don't see why, as this code has been tested before on different data-sets and appears to work just fine.

Comment: this is not true my guess is that you have `field: [['A', 'B']]`

Comment: Just spotted that, was a pain to find that record! Is there anyway to flatten or unwind this?

Comment: is field two dimensions array for all your documents?

Comment: No, I just have one row that looks like is [['A', 'B']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should work unless your data is organised differently. The following example data:

```
db.unwind.save({field:['A','B']} )
```

and the Mongo shell command:

```
db.unwind.aggregate([{
  "$unwind": "$field"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$field",
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "_id": 1
  }
}, ])
```

gives:

```
{ "_id" : "A", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "B", "count" : 1 }
```

If your data is in fact `field:[['A','B']]` you will need to add an additional `$unwind` parameter:

```
db.unwind.aggregate([{
  "$unwind": "$field"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$field",
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "_id": 1
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$_id"
}])
```